# Alchemical Gauntlet and runes

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e

An [Alchemical Gauntlet](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1971) is not a Base Weapon, so no runes can be added to it. I guess this is an oversight, just like [Alchemical Crossbows](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=118) had not been proper weapons when they first appeared in The Fall of Plaguestone adventure, but were later updated.

Until the update happens, is there any permanent way to use the extra 1d4 damage while I want a +1 on attacks?

Would a [Handwraps of Mighty Blows](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=441) work?

Comment: Why are you assuming that an alchemical gauntlet is not a [gauntlet](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=4) with an additional effect? Have you asked your GM/gaming group how they would rule that?

Comment: @Ifusaso Mostly because of the Alchemical Crossbow precedent. But you are probably right, it even links to the [gauntlet](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=4) in the description. Turn this into an answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The alchemical gauntlet is still a gauntlet

Although it could definitely be more clear, the alchemical gauntlet is still a [gauntlet](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=4) weapon (agile, free-hand) that can receive runes normally. Specifically, this line in alchemical gauntlet is what makes me pretty confident in this assessment

> The next three attacks made with the gauntlet deal 1d4 damage of the bomb's damage type **in addition to the gauntlet's normal damage.**

No 'normal damage' is defined, so I have to interpret it that its referring to the most logical existing item... the gauntlet weapon that *does* have defined normal damage.

I do agree that it was an oversight not to specifically call out the PCB gauntlet in the item description, but I also am reasonably confident that was the intent.